# Why is my Object undefined when I try to get a value from it

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lambda

So I get my data over a GET Request. I then load it to an Object from which I then try to get data. But when I console.log() a certain value from the Object, it says it is undefined.

```
 Users:UserService;  

  ngOnInit() {
    this.GetUsers();
  }
  GetUsers(){
    var tokenUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentuser'));
    this.config.GetUsers().subscribe( data => {
      this.Users = data.find(x => x.username == tokenUser.username);
      console.log(this.Users) //<= Works perfectly fine.
      console.log(this.Users.OrganisationName) //<= gives me an undefined
    });
  }
```

Here is the part where I try to assign the value (that is undefined) from the object.

```
 RegisterUserData(event:any){
    if(this.registerForm.valid){
      this.config.PostData(this.user).subscribe((data: UserService) => {
        this.user = {
          FirstName:undefined,
          LastName:undefined,
          Rights:"rw",
          OrganisationName: this.Users.OrganisationName,
          username:undefined,
          password:undefined,
          Email:undefined,

        }
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Then it must be `undefined`. Furthermore, you are not showing us where you are doing the console log, or in what order these code snippets are executed or related to each other... Please create a [MCVE]

Comment: Now after edit, if it gives you `undefined`, means that `OrganisationName` property does not exist on your `Users`. So how does `Users` look like?

Comment: Well if I look at the console.log of this.Users, the OrganisationName is defined.

Comment: Just add to your question the output of `console.log(this.Users)` BTW, the name is a bit misleading, sounds to me like it's an array, obviously it's not :) But that has nothing to do with it though, just a comment :)